# AWS CLI delete S3 non-empty bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to delete an Amazon S3 bucket that is not empty.

[this docs](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/delete-or-empty-bucket.md#delete-bucket-awscli) says I can delete using the following command

```
$ aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force
```

and to delete non empty I need to add `--force` flag which is not working.

Here is my command to delete the bucket, any clue why force flag wont work?

```
aws s3 rb s3://<bucket_name> --force --profile <profile_name>
```

Update:

I have tried following [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/empty-bucket.html) to empty the bucket but I don't see any output in the console:

`$ aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name --recursive`

Comment: Is it a versioned bucket? I seem to recall that `rb --force` doesn't remove previous versions, and thus the bucket will fail to delete after deleting the current version of all objects.

If it's a big bucket (millions of objects/versions), I usually create a life-cycle rule to empty the bucket. Then I can delete the bucket if I want to, or I can remove the life-cycle rule, and keep using it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try first to empty the bucket recursivelly and then delete it using rb command.

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name --recursive
aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force
```